# Can the pub / sub message ID be held as a number?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

Pub/sub guarantes that messageId is always unique number. Therefore, i use this id as deviceId and i hold this value on bigquery table. Google documents say this value string. But, messageId return 15-digit number according to my experiments. Should I keep this value as number on bigquery? Does it cause any trouble?

[Pubsub Message Format](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage)

Comment: why do you need as numeric? Do you want some numeric operation on them add/substract?

Comment: I do not use any numeric operation. messageId is kept on device as number and it is already developed by device team. Device program is low level and I try to prevent requesting a change on program unless it is absoultely necessary. But I cannot confirm the data type of messageId from any documentation page for Pub/Sub.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the max length of an [Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647) (10) and not the fact it contains only numeric values.
This is why you should keep the value as String and not as an Integer as defined in the documentation

Comment: Is 4 bytes Integer the only type we can use? What about 8 bytes or bigger integers?  BQ offers a type called "numeric" with storage size of 16 bytes and holds {38}.{9} digits long numbers, according to following documentation. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric-type

Comment: Sure you can use it just note that if Google will generate a String as their API state your code might not work

Answer (score 1):

Pub/sub guarantes that messageId is always *unique per topic* - not that it is a *number* [(ref)](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage)

The data type as stated in the docs is a String, so it can contain any unicode character.

So, as others have said, although it is a 15 digit number *now*, if at some point in 
the future, google generates a non-numeric string, or a number greater than what your low level code can store, then your app will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Google Support Says :
"MessageId consist of the maximum possible digits are 19. As long as an ID hasn't been used before (since they are unique), there can be up to 19 digits, but realistically that amount of digits may not be reached."